# Can I send a signal with a certain frequency and data rate using my android phone by changing in the kernel or by using GNU radio?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, signals, gnuradio, usrp

I want to transmit a certain data  with a certain data rate and my USRP doesn't support this high rate so I'm thinking if I can by any way change my kernel ( 2.6.35.7) to make the mobile transmit signal, or are there any apps that can do this ?
plz help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically yes, practically, no. The problem is that the RF blocks of a mobile phone are not documented and there is no way you can modify the phone to transmit anything unless you know how to modify the RF (modem) block of the chip inside your phone.

As for GNU Radio, I don't think it is possible to run GR on a mobile phone (yet).

Comment: where do you think I should start? to accomplish something like this in a short time?
thanks for you respond!!

Comment: Well, it all depends on what you want to do and what frequency you want to transmit. If your phone has USB OTG, then it can act as a host USB, then you can find a device that generates signals using USB then try to 'hack' it so it works with your mobile.

Comment: Something similar to this: http://www.windfreaktech.com/synthusb.html would work, but then you need to write the device driver SW for Android which can be pretty tough. There is no other 'easy' way of doing this. 
One other alternative is if your phone has a FM transmitter functionality, then you can create your data as a WAV file and then 'play' it over FM frequency band. But there are not that many phones on the market with an integrated FM transmitter.

Comment: I want to transmit signal on the RF band and this fm tx can't help me, also ur idea of using the a device that generates signals using usb is a good idea but we r out of many because we bought this useless USRP :).
one other thing can copy data I want from the kernel layer to the user space so I can read it, I want to know the parameters(control data)  of the N.W, and I think for sure there's a device driver that handle these parameters and I'm thinking if I can make  this driver copy these data to the user space then handle it.then I can take these data to help me when I work on GRC.
Thanks.

Comment: Actually USRP is pretty useful if you have a PC connected to it. I am using USRP1 and USRP N210 for some applications plus my own designed USRP1 copy with Altera Cyclone IV fpga instead of the old FPGA that is used on USRP1. Let me know if you need help with USRP, you can open a new questions so we can have the discussion there instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your phone isn't using the kernel you interact with to drive the radio. You can use an external, USB-attached (or other bus) radio interface, however connecting it to the rest of the system (unless you just want to use it in your own application) will be hard.

The cellular, wifi, bt and other radio interfaces have their own firmware, separate cpus, and usually involve heavy fines/jail for unauthorized modification (it's part of why your devices have "FCC ID" stickers and such - the firmware is tested to not make trouble for operation of other devices etc.).

Comment: so I think its impossible to do what I want.... but what if I want to copy data from the kernel layer to the user space so I can read it, I want to know the parameters(control data)  of the N.W, and I think for sure there's a device driver that handle these parameters and I'm thinking if I can make  this driver copy these data to the user space then handle it. (THANKS FOR YOU RESPOND )

Comment: If I understood right, what you're thinking is what is done by some form of radio interface layer. Cellular modems are driven with AT commands over real or simulated serial port most of the time. However, you can usually get some level of control over other chips, often due to certain tasks being farmed "upside" to normal cpu (to save costs, of course). However, you might not be able to get as much done as you want.

Best option to get such access would probably be to write a kernel module which would export it, or modify the existing drivers to export it, using kernel/userspace interfaces.